# Font Awesome 5 Free CSS/Webfonts pseudo character not showing

Tags: css, pseudo-element, font-awesome-5

I have a problem with the external link character not showing in a pseudo element style. Other characters are showing.

Font-Awesome 5.0.6 free, CSS/Webfont version, included via CDN:
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css

This works in my normal body content:

```
<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>
```

In CSS, this doesn't work:

```
a:after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: '\f35d';
}
```

Using another character in the pseudo does work:

```
a:after {
 font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
 content: '\f152';
}
```

According the to documentation the external link icon is part of the FA5 Free set: https://fontawesome.com/icons/external-link-alt?style=solid

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

*Edit 1*: 
JS Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/berjcaLy/4/

*Edit 2*: 
Accidentally found out that wrapping the `<a>` tag in `<b>` or `<strong>` will make the external link pseudo icon work. (JSfiddle updated, too)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

> font-weight:900

and it has to be 900.

Comment: Thanks, I found some other references now, too. It seems to be inconsistent to me though. In FA's Github it's mentioned that "Font Awesome 5 also requires `font-weight: 900;` when you use solid icons in custom css classes", however the `\f152` character worked just fine not being 900 while being fas (solid). GitHub: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946

Comment: After some more digging, all Font-Awesome 5 Free styles have to be available in the 'Solid' style. All solid styles need to be font-weight:900 if used in own CSS styles. `\f152` is also freely available in 'Regular' which doesn't require the 900 font width - hence it showed.

Comment: For reference:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css

Solid font-weight: 900 / Regular font weight: 400 / Light font-weight: 300 / Brands font-weight: 400